# function for reshaping data efficiently

Tags: r, dataframe, pivot, reshape, data-cleaning

I need to reshape a dataframe that looks like:

```
holdc
     
  country_n popClass_n org   P50M   P50L   P50U   P95M   P95L  P95U  P99M   P99L  P99U P99_9M P99_9L P99_9U
1   Austria     Adults ADG 0.0445 0.0392 0.0512 0.0914 0.0753 0.134 0.134 0.1010 0.230  0.152  0.115  0.258
2   Belgium     Adults ADG 0.0484 0.0398 0.0572 0.0944 0.0784 0.242 0.125 0.0994 0.338  0.171  0.131  0.690
3   Czechia     Adults ADG 0.0429 0.0352 0.0520 0.0901 0.0721 0.145 0.125 0.0948 0.296  0.183  0.121  0.434
4   Denmark     Adults ADG 0.0496 0.0415 0.0736 0.0885 0.0763 0.242 0.115 0.0984 0.363  0.159  0.125  0.564
5   Finland     Adults ADG 0.0422 0.0376 0.0486 0.0864 0.0746 0.106 0.117 0.1020 0.203  0.333  0.133  0.758
6    France     Adults ADG 0.0467 0.0383 0.0593 0.0893 0.0730 0.230 0.122 0.0986 0.353  0.179  0.129  0.578
```

into a new one that shall look like:

```
Concatenation    P50    P95   P99 P99_9
1  ADG_Adults_Austria_CI_50 0.0392 0.0914 0.134 0.152
2  ADG_Austria_Adults_CI2_5 0.0445 0.0753 0.101 0.115
3 ADG_Austria_Adults_CI97_5 0.0512 0.1340 0.230 0.258
```

and so forth for all `country_n`, `popClass_n`, and `org`.
Each row of the initial dataframe needs to split into three rows in the new dataframe: one row for the 'M' values, one row for the 'U' values and one row for the 'L' values.
I have written a function in base R that does it, but was wondering if you can suggest a more concise and fast solution, since I have to apply it to a a very large dataset.
My code so far is:

```
dfM <- f.arrange_perc(holdc,'CI_50')
dfL <- f.arrange_perc(holdc,'CI_2_5')
dfU <- f.arrange_perc(holdc,'CI_97_5')

df <- rbind(dfM, dfL,dfU)

f.arrange_perc <- function(holdc,sCI){
  df <- data.frame(matrix("", ncol = 5, nrow = 3*nrow(holdc))) 
  names(df) <- c('Concatenation','P50','P95','P99','P99_9')
  
  df$Concatenation <- paste(holdc$org,holdc$popClass_n,holdc$country_n, 
                            sCI, sep='_')
  if(sCI=='CI_50'){
    df$P50 <- holdc$P50M
    df$P95 <- holdc$P95M
    df$P99 <- holdc$P99M
    df$P99_9 <- holdc$P99_9M
  } else if (sCI=='CI_2_5'){
    df$P50 <- holdc$P50L
    df$P95 <- holdc$P95L
    df$P99 <- holdc$P99L
    df$P99_9 <- holdc$P99_9L
    
  } else if (sCI=='CI_97_5'){
    df$P50 <- holdc$P50U
    df$P95 <- holdc$P95U
    df$P99 <- holdc$P99U
    df$P99_9 <- holdc$P99_9U
    
  }
  return(df)
}
```

thanks for any hint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A one-liner:

```
tidyr::pivot_longer(df, cols = -c("country_n", "popClass_n", "org"), names_to = c(".value", "value"), names_pattern = "(P\\d+)([A-Z]+)")
```

As much as I can understand the desire to want to create a concatenation column, you're much better off not doing that, if not for [tidy data principles](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html), then simply because it makes it much easier to use the data later.

Update: answer for new data, with concatenation:

```
pivot_longer(df, cols = -c("country_n", "popClass_n", "org"), names_to = c(".value", "value"), names_pattern = "(P[\\d_]+)([A-Z]+)") |>
   mutate(Concatenation = paste(org, popClass_n, country_n, sep = "_"), .before = 1, .keep = "unused")
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 18 × 6
   Concatenation      value    P50    P95    P99 P99_9
   <chr>              <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
 1 ADG_Adults_Austria M     0.0445 0.0914 0.134  0.152
 2 ADG_Adults_Austria L     0.0392 0.0753 0.101  0.115
 3 ADG_Adults_Austria U     0.0512 0.134  0.23   0.258
 4 ADG_Adults_Belgium M     0.0484 0.0944 0.125  0.171
 5 ADG_Adults_Belgium L     0.0398 0.0784 0.0994 0.131
 6 ADG_Adults_Belgium U     0.0572 0.242  0.338  0.69 
 7 ADG_Adults_Czechia M     0.0429 0.0901 0.125  0.183
 8 ADG_Adults_Czechia L     0.0352 0.0721 0.0948 0.121
 9 ADG_Adults_Czechia U     0.052  0.145  0.296  0.434
10 ADG_Adults_Denmark M     0.0496 0.0885 0.115  0.159
11 ADG_Adults_Denmark L     0.0415 0.0763 0.0984 0.125
12 ADG_Adults_Denmark U     0.0736 0.242  0.363  0.564
13 ADG_Adults_Finland M     0.0422 0.0864 0.117  0.333
14 ADG_Adults_Finland L     0.0376 0.0746 0.102  0.133
15 ADG_Adults_Finland U     0.0486 0.106  0.203  0.758
16 ADG_Adults_France  M     0.0467 0.0893 0.122  0.179
17 ADG_Adults_France  L     0.0383 0.073  0.0986 0.129
18 ADG_Adults_France  U     0.0593 0.23   0.353  0.578
```

Comment: many thanks, looks great. As much as I tried with pivot_longet I could not manage. can you please explain the 'names_to' and the 'names_patterns'?

Comment: I also updated the data. the concatenation is needed as this is the input of an existing excel macro. thanks again

Comment: yeah sure! can do

Comment: so "(P\\d+)([A-Z]+)") is a regex pattern that looks for P, then a number (`\\d+`), then one or more uppercase letters `[A-Z]+`. The brackets create what is known as a capturing group - basically it just means whenever it finds a match for the things within the group, it keeps the matching text for processing, in this case, by names_to

Comment: to quote the documentation, '".value" indicates that the corresponding component of the column name defines the name of the output column containing the cell values, overriding values_to entirely'

Comment: it's kind of hard to explain...basically we are making the data longer, and the regular expression matching groups correspond to the items in the names_to, so the first one (".value") is the first matching group of the regex, and the second one is the "value" column that we create

Comment: very kind, thank you